# Can I obfuscate a PHP function call

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript function like this:

```
function delPhoto(thisPhotoID) {
  $("#php").load("delphoto.php?id=" + thisPhotoID);
}
```

This PHP function deletes the appropriate photo from a MySQL database, however anyone who looks at the source for the webpage could maliciously call the delphoto.php script with any number and delete random photos from the database.

Is there a way that I can obfuscate this function call so that this can't be done, or is there a way for the PHP function to refuse calls made to it from outside of the webpage?

Comment: This type of function and the associated back-end php code ought to be restricted to users that have been granted permissions to perform this type of action. You could rename the function and perhaps use an .htaccess rewrite rule to make the 'delphoto.php' page appears as 'fluffyandnice.php' but a malicious user might still plug in random numbers to see what happens... Best bet is to ensure these links only appear to those that are authorised and that the serverside code that handles the deletes tests for athenticated users.

Comment: You could get the `delphoto.php` to check that the user is logged in and then to stop a bad registered user make sure the photo is theirs to delete. Of course this depends onhow your system currently works

Comment: Obfuscation is not a form of authentication or security.  Just making that clear.  You should never leave a file that can manipulate any row of your database publicly accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if I can implement some kind of checksum such that `delphoto.php` would know that it was a valid call,

Eg:

```
delphoto.php?id=13&checksum=A4F8W9
```

where 13 equates to A4F8W9 and without the correct checksum it wouldn't be a valid call? So if someone wanted to try to delete image #14 they would need to figure out how to compute the correct checksum.

Comment: Using something like HMAC or some other request signing procedure would deter minor scriptkiddies, but it wouldn't stop someone who really wanted to screw up the site. If the request signing takes place on the front end, then that code must be available to the browser, and therefore to the attacker. who could simply call your javascript code from the js console to delete photos. Without proper backend validation of a valid user with permissions this is only a little better than just having it wide open

Comment: "If the request signing takes place on the front end" - I would think most people would recognise that exposing the keys used for encryption or hashing nullifies the benefits of encryption/hashing. If it were me I would go for a random value generated when the content was created and stored alongside it.

Comment: btw Andy, If you're really interested in security I'd suggest grabbing the book "Ajax Security" by Hoffman and Sullivan, it's a bit dated (2009) but it touches on a lot of important topics in securing frontend code and what to look for and guard against when dealing with issues like this. It's very readable too. You might find it useful in your career to have read it.

Answer (score 1):

**Security Issue 1:**
Never expose your back-end in this way : build a contoller;
Front-end must communicate only with controller, so all of your PHP scripts will be hidden for users
**Security Issue 2:**
Use the system of token for this kind of operations

1- Generate a random number, ex: using `uniqid()`, store it in list or associative array (User, Token) and push it in [Memcached](http://memcached.org/), [ANYEM](https://github.com/Halayem/ANYEM) or [Redis](http://redis.io/) Data Server
2- Generate your Link :

```
"controller?action=delete&imageId=" . $photoID . "&token=" . $tokenId";
```

3- When method **DELETE** is executed, verify the received `$tokenId`, if action is allowed, delete the stored Token from Data Server (it must be used only once)

Comment: It might be good to mention that a token like this should only be generated if the user has proper permission in the first place I think. But an **only once** token is a very good suggestion

Comment: @EdgeCaseBerg of course :) i've just pointed in the right way... the complete solution to keep an application secure will be to much long

Answer (score 0):

> however anyone who looks at the source for the webpage could maliciously call the delphoto.php script with any number and delete random photos from the database.

If I wanted to screw with your website, or even if I was just curious and poking around, having numeric ID's for your photos available to the world is a great place to start. Especially with something like "delphoto". If I wanted to place load on your server as well as mess with you in general, I would setup a script to hammer every single ID I could in parallel. Not only would this cause massive headaches for the user from data loss, but depending on if this call is deleting the photo from disk it could tie up server resources as well.

> Is there a way that I can obfuscate this function call so that this can't be done, or is there a way for the PHP function to refuse calls made to it from outside of the webpage?

It's good that you're conscious enough to understand that what you have currently is not secure. But obfuscation is no replacement for actual security. *Any* administrative function on a website should be secured by both a user system, and by a role management scheme. There should be a clear cut difference between a user and an admin as far as who can do what on a site.

I don't know if you're using a framework, but obviously we can't tell you how to secure the endpoint without seeing any code on how your user system works. But if you have one you need to look into the documentation and determine how to check if a user is:

1. Logged in
2. Has permission to run the action

Depending on what your system does, this might need to change. For example, an admin should be able to delete anything. But a user should only be able to delete their own photos. So part of the "permission to run the action" would have an ownership check.